How to mark Vision text recognition result as Sendable in Swift 6
I have the following code. It simply run Vision API to get the text from the image. I use very simple GCD to dispatch the heavy Vision operation to the background queue, and then dispatch it back to main queue for completion:
public struct TextRecognitionResult {
  let observation: VNRecognizedTextObservation
  let text: VNRecognizedText
  let rect: CGRect
}

public enum TextRecognitionUtil {
  
  private static let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "text_recognition", qos: .userInitiated)

  public static func process(
    image: UIImage,
    recognitionLevel: VNRequestTextRecognitionLevel,
    completion: @Sendable @escaping ([TextRecognitionResult]) -> Void)
  {
    guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else {
      completion([])
      return
    }
    let request = VNRecognizeTextRequest { (request, error) in
      guard
        error == nil,
        let observations = request.results as? [VNRecognizedTextObservation]
      else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          completion([])
        }
        return
      }
      
      var results = [TextRecognitionResult]()
      
      // Vision's origin is on bottom left
      let transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        .scaledBy(x: 1, y: -1)
        .translatedBy(x: 0, y: -image.size.height)
        .scaledBy(x: image.size.width, y: image.size.height)

      for observation in observations {
        guard let text = observation.topCandidates(1).first else { continue }
        let rect = observation.boundingBox.applying(transform)
        results += [TextRecognitionResult(observation: observation, text: text, rect: rect)]
      }
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        completion(results)
      }
    }
    
    request.recognitionLevel = recognitionLevel
    self.queue.async {
      let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage, options: [:])
      try? handler.perform([request])
    }
  }
}


This code violates Swift 6 concurrency, because TextRecognitionResult  is not Sendable:
Sending 'results' risks causing data races; this is an error in the Swift 6 language mode

However, my TextRecognitionResult can't be directly marked as Sendable, because VNRecognizedTextObservation and VNRecognizedText is not Sendable, and they are both types defined in Vision that I cannot change. This is a pretty common practice in GCD. I don't know what to do here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76415964/trouble-assigning-text-recognized-by-swifts-vision-library-to-the-instance-attr/76416822#76416822

A few observations:

I would declare your struct as Sendable:
public struct TextRecognitionResult: Sendable {
    let observation: VNRecognizedTextObservation
    let text: VNRecognizedText
    let rect: CGRect
}


I would import Vision as @preconcurrency:
@preconcurrency import Vision


I would make results immutable (using compactMap rather than a for loop):
public enum TextRecognitionUtil {
    enum TextRecognitionUtilError: Error {
        case noCgImage
        case notVNRecognizedTextObservation
    }

    private static let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "text_recognition", qos: .userInitiated)

    public static func process(
        image: UIImage,
        recognitionLevel: VNRequestTextRecognitionLevel = .accurate,
        completion: @Sendable @escaping (Result<[TextRecognitionResult], Error>) -> Void)
    {
        guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else {
            completion(.failure(TextRecognitionUtilError.noCgImage))
            return
        }

        let request = VNRecognizeTextRequest { request, error in
            guard
                error == nil,
                let observations = request.results as? [VNRecognizedTextObservation]
            else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.failure(error ?? TextRecognitionUtilError.notVNRecognizedTextObservation))
                }
                return
            }

            // Vision's origin is on bottom left
            let transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                .scaledBy(x: 1, y: -1)
                .translatedBy(x: 0, y: -image.size.height)
                .scaledBy(x: image.size.width, y: image.size.height)

            let results = observations.compactMap { (observation) -> TextRecognitionResult? in
                guard let text = observation.topCandidates(1).first else { return nil }
                let rect = observation.boundingBox.applying(transform)
                return TextRecognitionResult(observation: observation, text: text, rect: rect)
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(.success(results))
            }
        }

        request.recognitionLevel = recognitionLevel
        self.queue.async {
            let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage)
        }
    }
}

I also changed the closure return type to a Result so the caller could disambiguate between an error and no recognition results.


Swift 6 will probably simplify this a bit, but the above works in Xcode 15.4.


"I would import Vision as @preconcurrency:"
Do you mean Apple's Vision is not in a "concurrency ready" state? or do you mean my code that uses Vision is not in that good state?


The former. All the API (and some new Swift 6 language features) are in flux, and should settle down in the next few months, but until then, there are tons of Swift 6 false-positives in Apple’s own frameworks (and the @preconcurrency is a temporary feature to silence some of the overly cautious warnings). You didn’t do anything wrong. Apple is still tweaking this stuff and Swift 6 simplifies this a bit for us. See https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/269/whats-new-in-swift-6 for language features that make it easier for us to pass things that are not strictly Sendable.
