Vision Framework Causes EXC_BREAKPOINT Error in Xcode App Playground (.swiftpm) File
I’m trying to use the Vision framework in a Swift Playground to perform face detection on an image. The following code works perfectly when I run it in a regular Xcode project, but in an App Playground, I get the error:
Thread 12: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x10321c2a8)
Here's the code:
import SwiftUI
import Vision

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Face Detection")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()
            
            Image("me")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .onAppear {
                    detectFace()
                }
        }
    }
    
    func detectFace() {
        guard let cgImage = UIImage(named: "me")?.cgImage else { return }

        let request = VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest { request, error in
            if let results = request.results as? [VNFaceObservation] {
                print("Detected \(results.count) face(s).")
                for face in results {
                    print("Bounding Box: \(face.boundingBox)")
                }
            } else {
                print("No faces detected.")
            }
        }
        
        let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage, options: [:])
        do {
            try handler.perform([request]) // This line causes the error.
        } catch {
            print("Failed to perform Vision request: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

The error occurs on this line:
try handler.perform([request])

Details:

This code runs fine in a normal Xcode project (.xcodeproj).
I'm using an App Playground instead (.swiftpm).
The image is being included in the .xcassets folder.

Is there any way I can mitigate this issue? Please do not recommend switching to .xcodeproj, as I am making a submission for Apple's Swift Student Challenge, and they require that I use .swiftpm.

Try converting to async await with something like this sample https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76415964/trouble-assigning-text-recognized-by-swifts-vision-library-to-the-instance-attr/76416822#76416822 just the methodology the sample is a different vision function

@loremipsum Thank you, that was helpful. I have posted my solution.

Using the methodology behind this solution, I was able to fix the issue.
I have now incorporated modern Swift concurrency utilizing async/await and withCheckedThrowingContinuation.
import SwiftUI
@preconcurrency import Vision

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Face Detection")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()
            
            Image("me")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .task {
                    await detectFace()
                }
        }
    }
    
    func detectFace() async {
        guard let cgImage = UIImage(named: "me")?.cgImage else { return }

        let request = VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest()
        let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage, options: [:])

        do {
            try await performVisionRequest(request: request, handler: handler)
            if let results = request.results {
                print("Detected \(results.count) face(s).")
                for face in results {
                    print("Bounding Box: \(face.boundingBox)")
                }
            } else {
                print("No faces detected.")
            }
        } catch {
            print("Failed to perform Vision request: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    private func performVisionRequest(request: VNRequest, handler: VNImageRequestHandler) async throws {
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            do {
                try handler.perform([request])
                continuation.resume()
            } catch {
                continuation.resume(throwing: error)
            }
        }
    }
}


Your question/answer are not quite equivalent the async part isn’t needed because you aren’t doing anything asynchronous work. You removed the Request closure. This version is fully synchronous

@loremipsum Is withCheckedThrowingContinuation not an asynchronous call?

It is, but the code you have within it isn’t. The handler in the sample code and the handler in your original code is asynchronous. With your new code you don’t need any asynchronous.
