Vision bounding box is offset in the y coordinates
I was able to successfully setup the text recognition in a static image using Apple's documentation, after that I tried using the guide to add bounding boxes using the same link with the following code:
func recongizeText()
{
    // Create a new image-request handler.
    let cgImage = self.nsImage!.cgImage(forProposedRect: nil, context: nil, hints: nil)

    let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage!)


    // Create a new request to recognize text.
    let request = VNRecognizeTextRequest(completionHandler: recognizeTextHandler)
    do {
        // Perform the text-recognition request.
        try requestHandler.perform([request])
    } catch {
        print("Unable to perform the requests: \(error).")
    }

}
func recognizeTextHandler(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
    guard let observations =
            request.results as? [VNRecognizedTextObservation] else {
        return
    }
    let recognizedStrings = observations.compactMap { observation in
        // Return the string of the top VNRecognizedText instance.
        return observation.topCandidates(1).first?.string
    }
    let boundingRects: [CGRect] = observations.compactMap { observation in


        // Find the top observation.
        guard let candidate = observation.topCandidates(1).first else { return .zero }
        
        // Find the bounding-box observation for the string range.
        let stringRange = candidate.string.startIndex..<candidate.string.endIndex
        let boxObservation = try? candidate.boundingBox(for: stringRange)
        // Get the normalized CGRect value.
        let boundingBox = boxObservation?.boundingBox ?? .zero

   // Convert the rectangle from normalized coordinates to image coordinates.
        return VNImageRectForNormalizedRect(boundingBox,
                                            Int(self.nsImage!.size.width),
                                            Int(self.nsImage!.size.height))
    }
    self.boundingRects = boundingRects

For the UI part I just added a simple overlay:
struct BoundingBoxView: View {
var nsImage: NSImage // The NSImage to display
    var normalizedBoundingBoxes: [CGRect] // Array of normalized bounding boxes
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(nsImage: nsImage)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .overlay(
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    // Draw normalized bounding boxes
                    ForEach(normalizedBoundingBoxes.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                        let normalizedBox = normalizedBoundingBoxes[index]
                        Rectangle()
                            .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 2)
                            .frame(width: normalizedBox.size.width, height: normalizedBox.size.height)
                            .position(x: normalizedBox.midX, y: normalizedBox.midY)
                    }
                }
            )    }

But if I run this I get the following bounding boxes:


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75273987/wrong-offsets-when-displaying-multiple-vnrecognizedobjectobservation-boundingbox/75316939#75316939

@loremipsum, thank you that worked but is it doable without flipping the X axis by 180 degrees? I'm trying to redact the text by letting the user click on it but by flipping it, it's messing up the whole redacting thing

One of the VNImageRectForNormalizedRect can give you the correct coordinates. They have similar names I don’t remember the right one off the top of my head.

@loremipsum, are you sure because what I meant was that when I tried to click the upper bounding box it redacted the lower bounding box and vice versa, is that because we flipped the x axis?

Maybe,if you didn’t map them to the “redaction” correctly
